# Is it possible to get supercategory pages ids?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki-api

It is possible to obtain ids of subcategories, with

```
cmprop=ids
```

parameter for `list=categorymembers` query.

But I cant find a way to obtain the same for supercategories list for `prop=categorymembers` query.

I tried with

```
clprop=ids
```

by analogy, but failed (this parameter was ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens basically because in MediaWiki, the relation is between a page (the subcategory) and a *category name* (the supercategory). So, some page can have a supercategory that doesn't exist (doesn't have a pageid) and this is also how the relation is stored in the database.

I think this is the reason why `prop=categories` doesn't show you article ids. You can work around that by using a generator that shows you the id for each page in the list of supercategories. Something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categories&prop=info&titles=Category%3AComputer%20programming&ginprop=